# Stratum specific estimates in a model with an interaction term

Tags: logistic, interaction, epidemiology

Lets say I have a logistic regression model predicting the log odds of mild cognitive impairment (MCI) and my exposures of interest are age, education and carbohydrate intake. I expect that the associate between carbohydrate intake and log odds of MCI might vary across levels of age, so I intend on including a product term.

I have centered my age variable at 60 years and it measured in 5 year units. Carbohydrate intake is centered at 200g/day and is in 50g/day units.

My model is like so:
log odds (MCI) = B0 + B1*carbs* + B2*age* + B3*university* + B4*carbsxage*

My gesture at understanding these coefficients is:

B1 - log OR for a 50g increase in carbs, when age equals 60 years;

B2 - log OR for a 5 year increase in age, when carbs equals 200g;

B3 - log OR for university education, adjusted for age and carbs;

B4 - Change in the log OR for carbs by increasing age by 5 years.

If that model were to give clear evidence for the interaction, I would be able to calculate the effect of carb intake on MCI across several strata of age:

log OR for carbs at 60 years = B1

log OR for carbs at 65 years = B1 + B4

log OR for carbs at 70 years = B1 + 2*B4

My question is, in this hypothetical, is this a coherent way to display results in the context of interaction? One problem is I don't see any way that I can calculate confidence intervals for these estimates. Is one better off simply performing separate regressions on the data stratified by age (i.e. 60-65, 65-70, 70-75 years)?  Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing the results of the regression with the coefficients, their standard errors, CI, and p-values is a standard way to proceed. Showing a few specific examples as you propose also makes sense. Some find nomograms to be be a good way to display results.

To get confidence intervals for predictions from specific combinations of predictor values you need not only the coefficients and their standard errors but also the variance-covariance matrix among the coefficient estimates. In R, for example, that's obtained via the `vcov()` function applied to the object returned by the regression. You then use the formula for the [variance of a weighted sum of correlated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables) to get the variance (and thus standard errors and CI) for the prediction for each particular combination of predictor variables. Standard software that has some type of `predict()` function can make this easier for you.

Comment: Excellent. I was imaging that I could do this with predict(), but I thought that it could only be used to generate predicted values of Y, rather than estimates and CI's for predictor estimates. How would one go about using predict to calculate the latter?

Comment: @Lachlan for `predict.glm` in R you can set `se.fit=TRUE` in the function call. As the coefficient estimates in logistic regression are assumed to be normally distributed, the 95% CI are 1.96 times the standard error. You might consider using the R [`emmeans` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=emmeans), which many find to be a useful interface for such calculations for a very wide variety of models.